# Rendering partials with Ajax in single modal breaks functionality

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I have a simple modal with 2 options (login and register).

**Modal code:**

```
<div class="modal fade" id="welcome" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog log-modal">
        <div class="modal-content log-input">                           

            <div class="ajax-partal-field">

                <%= render partial: "reusable/login" %>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**_login.html.erb**

```
 <div class="modal-header clearfix">


                                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                                <h4 class="modal-title pull-left">Laipni lūdzam</h4>


                                   <%= link_to reusable_registration_path,:class=>"pull-right",:remote=>true do %>

                                               <span>Reģistrēties</span>
                                    <%end%>


                            </div>

                            <div class="modal-body clearfix">
                           <%= form_for(resource,:html => {"data-parsley-validate" => true,:class => "user-form"},:remote=> true,format: :json,as: resource_name, url: session_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                       <%= f.email_field :email,:class=>"user-input form-control" ,:id=>"user-name" ,:placeholder=>"Lietotājvārds *", autofocus: true ,required: true%>  
                                         <a class="help-button" href="#">?</a>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                       <%= f.password_field :password,:class=>"user-input form-control", :id=>"password", :placeholder=>"Parole *", autocomplete: "off",required: true %>
                                    <a class="help-button" href="#">?</a>
                                </div>

                                <span class="validation-message" style="color: white;">Nepareiza parole!</span>

                                <div class="remember-me">
                                        <div class="squared">
                                             <%= f.check_box :remember_me, :id=>"remember-me"%> 

                                            <label style="left: 0px;" for="remember-me"><span>Atcerēties mani</span></label>


                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                        <%= button_tag "PIESLĒGTIES", data: { disable_with: "Strādā..." } ,:class=>"blue-button btn btn-default"   %>

                                            <%= link_to reusable_password_recovery_path,:remote=> true, :class => "pull-right forgot-pass" do %>

                                                 <span>Aizmirsāt paroli</span>
                                            <% end %>
                           <%end%>

                            </div>
```

When a user triggers the log in the modal, he has the option to change the modal content to registration form. And if a user triggers the registration modal, he has the option to switch to log in. He can continuously change it.

**Controller:**

```
 def login
    respond_to do |format|
         format.js
       end
  end

  def registration
       respond_to do |format|
         format.js
       end
  end
```

I have appropriate js files like **login.js.erb**

```
$(".ajax-partal-field").html("<%= escape_javascript(render('login')) %>");
```

Problem:

When I trigger login modal for the first time everything works. When I click for the registration form, the form loses its javascript functionality. For example.

I can't click checkbox after I load partial using ajax.

```
<%= f.check_box :remember_me, :id=>"remember-me"%> 

    <label style="left: 0px;" for="remember-me"><span>Atcerēties mani</span></label>
```

Comment: What happens when you change the view from login to registration or the reverse ? Does it close the modal, waits for the server's response and open a new modal or does it empty the modal and puts the server's reponse in the modal's content ?

Comment: @MrYoshiji It just renders other partial in place of previos partial. It does not close and reopen anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are aware, you lose your handlers as you replace the html elements that your javascript is dependent upon.

To fix the errors, append your javasacript handlers on an element that will not get replaced.  For example:

```
$('body').on('click', '.class-of-elem-that-will-get-swapped-out', function() {
  console.log("this will work")
})
```

instead of:

```
$('.class-of-elem-that-will-get-swapped-out').click(function() {
  console.log("this will never print after the html gets swapped out")
})
```

Comment: tnx but still cant figure it out. I am rendering forms as complete partials. so it should keep handlers .